# Rails 4.2 rspec - expect http status to be 201 but is always 200

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have the following create method.

```
def create

     User.transaction do
          @u = User.create(user_params)
          @u.create_role!(account_params)
          @u.create_address!(address_params)
     end

      if params.has_key?("manager_id") then
         if Manager.exists?(params["sam_id"]) then
             @u.update(manager_id: params["manager_id"])
         else
             raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, "The Mananger with id #{params["manager_id"]} does not exist"
         end
     end

     res = @u.attributes.except("created_at","updated_at").merge(
         @u.address.attributes.except("updated_at","created_at")
     ){|key,v1,v2|v1}

     render json: res.to_json, status: :created
 end
```

The returned http status is either  `201` or `404` if some validations for the role and address are not met. In my rspec test i check the returned status with

```
 it "returns status - 201 " do
      expect(response).to have_http_status(201)
 end
```

But i always receive this failure message

```
12) Api::V1::UserController POST #create Success returns status - 201 
  Failure/Error: expect(response).to have_http_status(201)
    expected the response to have status code 201 but it was 200
  # ./spec/controllers/api/v1/user_controller_spec.rb:126:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The other tests for the POST request  pass. So for example the matcher for the return schema for the just created user runs  successfully.I do not understand why my test always return `200 ok` and not `201`

Comment: What do you get in the server console?

Comment: Curl works good. I get `Completed 201 Created in 226ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 19.5ms)`

Comment: Did you try expecting this way `expect(response).to have_http_status(:created)`?

Comment: Why do you use 404 Not Found in case the request is not correct? Maybe 400 Bad Request would be a better idea

Comment: Yeah thats true :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform the request first before expecting the status code.

If the request has not been performed yet, `response.status_code` will return 200.